# Iterate over rows and write a new column if condition meets python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have two separate df frames that I want to compare:

f1

```
P53-Malat1
Neat1-Malat1
Gap1-Malat1
```

and f2:

```
intA,intB
P53-Malat1,Neat1-Malat1
Gap1-Malat1,Malat1-Pias3
```

I want to iterate over the rows of each column in f2 and see id it is inside the f1. If yes then print that row + "found" and if no then print that row+"not_found" in a seperate column.

The same for column two in f2.

I tried this approach but it doesn't work - am I missing something?

```
with open("f1.txt","r") as f1:
    content = f1.read().splitlines()
    #print(content)

f2 = pd.read_csv("f2.csv")


f2["col1_search"] = f2.apply(lambda x: x["intA"]+"_found" if x in content else x["intA"]+"_not_found", axis=1)
f2["col2_search"] = f2.apply(lambda x: x["intB"]+"_found" if x in content else x["intB"]+"_not_found", axis=1)
```

so the desired output should be f2 in this format:

```
col1_search,col2_search
P53-Malat1_found,Neat1-Malat1_found
Gap1-Malat1_found,Malat1-Pias3_not_found
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your best option for something like this would probably be to use something like np.where(condition, if_true_this, if_false_this). If you can change your answer a way to copy your data into a df I think you would be able to get a little more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly content is a list not a dataframe.  If this is the case you can us `.isin` which will return `True` or `False` for each row which can be mapped to whatever suffix you want.

```
import pandas as pd
content = ['P53-Malat1','Neat1-Malat1','Gap1-Malat1']


f2 = pd.DataFrame({'intA': {0: 'P53-Malat1', 1: 'Gap1-Malat1'},
                   'intB': {0: 'Neat1-Malat1', 1: 'Malat1-Pias3'}})

f2['col1_search'] = f2.intA + f2.intA.isin(content).map({True:'_found',False:'_not_found'})
f2['col2_search'] = f2.intB + f2.intB.isin(content).map({True:'_found',False:'_not_found'})
```

Output

```
          intA          intB        col1_search             col2_search
0   P53-Malat1  Neat1-Malat1   P53-Malat1_found      Neat1-Malat1_found
1  Gap1-Malat1  Malat1-Pias3  Gap1-Malat1_found  Malat1-Pias3_not_found
```

Or perhaps if you have many columns:

```
(f2 + f2.isin(content).replace({True:'_found',False:'_not_found'})).add_suffix('_search')
```

Output

```
         intA_search             intB_search
0   P53-Malat1_found      Neat1-Malat1_found
1  Gap1-Malat1_found  Malat1-Pias3_not_found
```

which could be merged back to the original data with

```
pd.concat([f2,(f2 + f2.isin(content).replace({True:'_found',False:'_not_found'})).add_suffix('_search')], axis=1)
```

Output

```
          intA          intB        intA_search             intB_search
0   P53-Malat1  Neat1-Malat1   P53-Malat1_found      Neat1-Malat1_found
1  Gap1-Malat1  Malat1-Pias3  Gap1-Malat1_found  Malat1-Pias3_not_found
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how you would use the np.where

```
data = {'Category' : ['First', 'Second', 'Third'], 
        'First_Numbers' : [10, 10, 10],
        'Second_Numbers' : [20, 20, 20],
        'Third_Numbers' : [9, 21, 15]
       } 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
comp_column = np.where((df['Third_Numbers'] < df['Second_Numbers']) & (df['Third_Numbers'] > df['First_Numbers']), 'found', 'not found')
df['check'] = comp_column
df
```

I inserted some sample data which you should be able to replace with your own data. Now I see your wanting to compare between 2 different dfs so I would recommend merging them so that you are only working on a single df. This is the best documentation for merging/joining/concating pandas df: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Answer (score 0):

```
f2 = pd.read_csv("f2.csv")
def transform(path:str,x):
    with open(path,"r") as f1:
         content = f1.read().splitlines()
    if x in content:
        return f"{x}_found"
    return f"{x}_not_found"

f2["col1_search"] = f2['intA'].apply(lambda x:transform("f2.csv", x.intA),axis=1)
f2["col2_search"] = f2['intB'].apply(lambda x:transform("f2.csv", x.intB),axis=1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).